# Soft Keyboard makes BottomView hide using AndroidSwipeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, swipe

I'm developing an Android app that uses the library [AndroidSwipeLayout](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) to implement the "Edit profile" functionality of my app.

My problem is when the swipe happens I have an EditText that I need to change but when the keyboard comes out the bottom view hides and I can only see the surface so I can never edit the fields.

Do you have any idea how can I manage to edit the field without the bottom view hiding when the soft keyboard comes out?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

in your manifest as described in the developer docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

also adjustResize might work. Depends on what you want.

Comment: I tried this but the only change was that the screen was like pulled up when the keyboard showed up. The swipeLayout keeps hiding the bottom view and showing the surface view. Any other ideas?

Comment: ah - ok. It seems a misunderstood the question. I thought i was hidden by the keyboard. I'm not familiar with the AndroidSwipeLayout library. But maybe it needs some redraw after the keyboard appeared. Have you tried calling invalidate() on the layout after the keyboard appears?